# Why are there errors reported inside a standard library header after adding a search directory in compiler options?

Tags: c++, g++, codeblocks, mingw32

I have a project in CodeBlocks (MinGW32) which is setup like this :

```
Foo/src/somefile1.cpp
Foo/src/somefile2.cpp
Foo/src/somefile1.h
...
```

Headers are included that way :

```
#include "somefile1.h"
```

In order to be able to compile I have added the following directory in "Project options" > "Search directories" (as a relative path) :

```
src
```

After adding that folder, the project compiles. However, if I include a standard header like `<ctime>` the following errors appears in ctime header file :

```
'::clock_t' has not been declared
'::time_t' has not been declared
...
```

and so on for all lines inside the `std namespace` brackets of ctime. If I remove the `src` folder from search directories, I can compile again.

I have reduced the code to the bare minimum, removed all files except `main.cpp`, but the problem is still there :

```
#include <ctime> //errors if "src" folder added in search folders

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    time(NULL); //does not compile
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: did you try to use `std::time_t`instead of `::time_t` ?

Comment: You mean to modify ctime header file directly ? Here is how ctime looks : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/libstdc++/api/a01181_source.html All errors appears inside std namespace lines

Comment: Do not, under any circumstances, modify Standard Library header files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem :

In the project I'm trying to compile there is a file named "time.h".

It has same name as standard library time.h file. Because of this, inside ctime file, the time.h of the project is included (which doesn't contains clock_t and other definitions) and thus ctime cannot be compiled.

As solution, I have simply renamed time.h of the project to a not reserved name.

Comment: It seems that [gcc's search behavior](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) on `#include <>`s and `#include ""`s is relevant here, then: Directories added to the search path with `-I` will be searched for both, and in the case of `<>` before any other option, unless the deprecated `-I-` option is used. The `-iquote` option will add a directory only to the search path for quoted includes. Since `<ctime>` `#include <>`s `time.h`, an `-I` option will override the location of `time.h` if the specified directory contains a `time.h` file.

Answer (score 0):

The `<ctime>` header puts the names into the `std` namespace, so you want:

```
std::time(NULL);
```

You probably have a `using namespace std;` in one of your own header files - don't do that.

Also, you typically want to include your own headers like this:

```
#include "somefile1.h"
```

Comment: Adding `std::` does not solve the problem, there is still errors reported in `ctime` header. `using namespace std;` => I don't have any, the problem occurs even with minimal example provided in the OP. Header : I use double quotes, I made the error while typing the question on SO.

Comment: @jagged The screenshot is of the standard library header, which is placing the library names in the std namespace - it's correct.

Comment: @latedeveloper so it is. My mistake.