# ::clock has not been declared

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

i am trying to build a little qt project using Qt Creator.
i added this driver to my project: https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver

i includes its libraries,

and when i am trying to build i get this:

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++1y -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../OfirWebDriverProj -I. -I../ofir/qtwebdriver/out/dist/desktop/release/libs -I../ofir/qtwebdriver/out/dist/desktop/release/libs -I../ofir/qtwebdriver/out/dist/desktop/release/libs -I../ofir/qtwebdriver/out/dist/desktop/release/libs -I../ofir/qtwebdriver/out/desktop/release/Default/lib.target -I../ofir/qtwebdriver/out/desktop/release/Default/lib.target -I../ofir/qtwebdriver/out/desktop/release/Default/lib.target -I../ofir/qtwebdriver/out/desktop/release/Default/lib.target -I../ofir/qtwebdriver/out/dist/desktop/release/h/base -I../ofir/qtwebdriver/out/dist/desktop/release/h -I../ofir/qtwebdriver/out/dist/desktop/release/Test -I/opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I. -I/opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../OfirWebDriverProj/main.cpp

In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/chrono:41:0,
                 from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:59,
                 from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:46,
                 from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qapplication.h:44,
                 from /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/QApplication:1,
                 from ../OfirWebDriverProj/main.cpp:2:

/usr/include/c++/7/ctime:64:11: error: ‘::clock’ has not been declared
   using ::clock;
           ^~~~~

/usr/include/c++/7/ctime:65:11: error: ‘::difftime’ has not been declared
   using ::difftime;
           ^~~~~~~~

/usr/include/c++/7/ctime:66:11: error: ‘::mktime’ has not been declared
   using ::mktime;
           ^~~~~~

/usr/include/c++/7/ctime:67:11: error: ‘::time’ has not been declared
   using ::time;
           ^~~~

/usr/include/c++/7/ctime:68:11: error: ‘::asctime’ has not been declared
   using ::asctime;
           ^~~~~~~

/usr/include/c++/7/ctime:69:11: error: ‘::ctime’ has not been declared
   using ::ctime;
           ^~~~~

/usr/include/c++/7/ctime:70:11: error: ‘::gmtime’ has not been declared
   using ::gmtime;
           ^~~~~~

/usr/include/c++/7/ctime:71:11: error: ‘::localtime’ has not been declared
   using ::localtime;
           ^~~~~~~~~

/usr/include/c++/7/ctime:72:11: error: ‘::strftime’ has not been declared
   using ::strftime;
           ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with you GCC setup, but can't tell what...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably too late to help the original poster but based on [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43814051/1518546) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41371718/1518546), you probably have a file named `time.h` in your source. Rename the file (and adjust your code that includes it) to something else like `time_utils.h` and it should compile.